# Dynamic UITableView with images

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimageview, autolayout

There are similar questions, but non of the answers worked for me. In a dynamic table I want to display images that have different heigh. Each cell has a `UIImageView` with `contentMode = .scaleAspectFit` so the image nicely takes the width of the table and takes the height as much as needed.

Cell has 4 constraints: 
[image]

Table view controller:

```
class TableTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: ImageTableViewCell.self), for: indexPath) as! ImageTableViewCell

        let image = indexPath.row == 0 ? UIImage(named: "1.jpg")! : UIImage(named: "2.jpg")!
        cell.customImageView.image = image

        return cell
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

As you can see that the height of the cell is incorrect (red background of the image view on top and bottom of the image view). I believe this happens because `intrinsicContentSize` of the image view is equal to the image size and thats why the height of the cell is calculated incorrectly (content mode is not taken into account). I tried calculating height of the image and adding height constraint for the image view:

```
cell.heightConstraint.constant = cell.frame.width * image.size.height /  image.size.width
```

but it breaks cell's content view constraints.

The project can be downloaded [here>>](https://bitbucket.org/paleksandrs/dynamicimagecellsintableview/src)

Comment: So basically you want tableview which have dynamic height cell?

Comment: Set Constraints properly

Comment: @Dharmesh Kheni yes, so cell's height is equal to the image height.

Comment: @Harish very constructive answer LOL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `ImageTableViewCell.swift`

```
import UIKit

class ImageTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var customImageView: UIImageView!

    internal var aspectConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint? {
        didSet {
            if oldValue != nil {
                customImageView.removeConstraint(oldValue!)
            }
            if aspectConstraint != nil {
                customImageView.addConstraint(aspectConstraint!)
            }
        }
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        aspectConstraint = nil
    }

    func setPostedImage(image : UIImage) {

        let aspect = image.size.width / image.size.height

        aspectConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: customImageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: customImageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, multiplier: aspect, constant: 0.0)

        customImageView.image = image
    }
}
```

And into your `TableTableViewController.swift` your `cellForRowAt` method will be:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ImageTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageTableViewCell

    let image = imageArr[indexPath.row]
    cell.setPostedImage(image: image!)
    return cell
}
```

And declare your `imageArr` this way:

```
let imageArr = [UIImage(named: "1.jpg"), UIImage(named: "2.jpg")]
```

And your compete code will be:

```
import UIKit

class TableTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let imageArr = [UIImage(named: "1.jpg"), UIImage(named: "2.jpg")]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ImageTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageTableViewCell

        let image = imageArr[indexPath.row]
        cell.setPostedImage(image: image!)
        return cell
    }
}
```

And [THIS](https://i.gyazo.com/b1929a49fd443f92ad66c2eb8417757b.gif) will be your result.

**EDIT:**

To fix constraint issue set `aspectConstraint` priority to `999` and `aspectConstraint` will be:

```
internal var aspectConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint? {
    didSet {
        if oldValue != nil {
            customImageView.removeConstraint(oldValue!)
        }
        if aspectConstraint != nil {
            aspectConstraint?.priority = 999  //add this
            customImageView.addConstraint(aspectConstraint!)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately your code breaks constraints. Check the console when you run it - Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

Comment: To fix breaking constraints you need to set constraint priority to 999. I will accept the answer when you update it. Thanks

Comment: Removing the expected size + automaticDimension doesn't break anything on my side (I don't set any height in the cell neither). Is that important to add it anyway ?