# Make tableview cell height dynamically after download image from server

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewautomaticdimension

I have one cell in which i show images download from server now. Right now i show image with static height but now i want to make dynamic like facebook and instagram. For example if i upload image 320 * 100 then my cell need to become 300*100. and also suggest server side changes if required 
I am using afnetworking image loading classes.

Here is my cell design .
[image]

**EDIT:**
I tried given solution but now issue is that cell resize with jerk when second time it's come in **cellforindexpath** method. This will happen in first cell only.

Comment: tableview or collectionview?

Comment: @AnshadRasheed in Title he mentioned Tableview.

Comment: @chirag have a look at this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42163132/dynamic-uitableview-with-images?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: image its marked as collectionview

Comment: @AnshadRasheed i used collection view also because there are paging for show images.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48385949/dynamic-cell-height-with-sdwebimage/48386279#48386279

Comment: @Aleem your suggestion is good but it is not happening in my case please again read my question.

Comment: try this way https://github.com/bibinvazhappillil/Dynamic-tableView-Cell

Answer (score 4):

I have done similar task, showing the images on the table and resize the tableview cell so that the image is shown along the fullscreen width

**Height For Row At IndexPath**

```
var cachedHeight = [IndexPath : CGFloat]()
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtindexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    let default_height : CGFloat = 332.0

    // lookup for cached height
    if let height = cachedHeight[indexPath]{
        return height
    }

    // no cached height found
    // so now try for image so that cached can be calculated and cached
    let cache : SDImageCache = SDImageCache.shared()
    let image : UIImage? = cache.imageFromDiskCache(forKey: self.viewModel?.getProductImage(of: indexPath.row, at: 0))

    if let image = image{
        let baseHeight : CGFloat = CGFloat(332 - 224)   // cell height - image view height
        let imageWidth = self.tableView.frame.size.width
        let imageHeight = image.size.height * imageWidth / image.size.width

        cachedHeight[indexPath] = imageHeight + baseHeight
        return cachedHeight[indexPath]!
    }

    //
    //  even if the image is not found, then
    //  return the default height
    //
    return default_height
}
```

**Cell For Row At IndexPath**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let sdCache = SDImageCache.shared()
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyXYZCell", for: indexPath) as! AuctionListTableViewCell
    let imageURL = self.viewModel?.getProductImage(of: indexPath.row, at: 0)

    if let imageURL = imageURL {
        if (sdCache.imageFromCache(forKey: imageURL) != nil) {
            //
            //  image data already persist on disk,
            //  cell height update required
            //
            cell.auctionImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL.init(string: imageURL), completed: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            cell.auctionImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL.init(string: imageURL), completed: { (image, err, cacheType, url) in
                self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
            })
        }
    }

    //other cell customization code

    return cell
}
```

I have used [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). You can use it, or find similar api in `AFNetworking`.

Keynotes:

1. Here `cachedHeight` is used to cache the height of the cell indexed by the `IndexPath`, because reading the image from the disk is quiet I/O exhaustive task, which results lag in the table view scroll.
2. In `heightForRow` i checked that, is the image is in cache, if in cache, then calculate the height, store it into the `cachedHeight`, otherwise return the default height. (My default height is calculated for my placeholder image)
3. In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` i have checked is the image is in cache. If the image is in cache, then no reload is required as the height is already calculated. Otherwise i attempt a network fetch, when the fetch completed i request to tableview to reload that cell.

Hope it helps, Happy coding.

Comment: Yes i tried your solution but i have one issue you calculate height of the contact but i used UITableViewAutomaticDimension, So first time image load with default height and when it reload then with jerk it become bigger. So is there any way to stop that jerk.

Comment: to stop the jerking use `self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)` and go to the interface builder, select the tableview, in the `size inspector` section uncheck the `Row height` Automatic option and uncheck the `Estimate` option. Another thing, please clarify how did you use the `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. I mean where & how did you set it ?

Comment: Finally it's done , jerking gone when i set height of collection view in cellForRow, and charm it's working

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this problem.
If you have to make imageview height and width dynamic then ask server to send image width and Height in API response.
Once you get both, according to image width and screen width calculate the image height.
Take constraint of image height. And assign calculated height to image height constraint.

To calculate image height use below formula:-

```
imageHeight =  (screen_width * actual_image_height) / actual_image_width
```